# connect to localhost port inside the docker container is refused

Tags: docker

Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

It's my *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

EXPOSE 5432
```

build the container:

```
 $ docker build -t expose_5432_port .
```

run the container:

```
docker run -ti expose_5432_port /bin/bash
```

I try to connect the port inside the container:

```
root@5f15a7ebd280:/# nc -v -z 127.0.0.1 5432
nc: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5432 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

How to connect the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected.

EXPOSE opens a way to connect to port 5432 in the container but as it states `connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5432 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`, you are able to connect/reach to the port successfully but since there is nothing running on that port it's saying connection refused. You got to make some application run on port 5432.

Ref- 
https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message

Comment: indeed, when you start for example `docker run -d postgres` this will work because a postgres service is running on port 5432 (check its dockerfile)